# Show all settings in gpedit

Tags: windows-10

I have two computers running `gpedit`. First one has convenient feature that allows to see "All Settings":

[image]

While other PC does not have such shortcuts. Why and how to enable them on other system?

UPD gpedit and OS versions

PC with all settings:
Windows 10 Home 64 bit,
gpedit version 1

[image]

PC with all settings:
Windows 10 Enterprice 64 bit,
gpedit version 1

[image]

Comment: What is the OS version & edition of the two machines?

Comment: In addition to the OS version & edition request, also provide version information from the two 'About...' items located under the 'Help' menu in gpedit.

Comment: Please find versions provided in question body UPD